# Is it possible to estimate the number of primes between 0 and a 128 bit number?

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography, visualization, coloring

I'm attempting to visualize an RSA public/private key pair, or a SHA2 hash.  In order to reduce that massive number that is meaningful to humans I'm looking at this [SHA2 visualization function](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/74896/2139) to [express large numbers as an image](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/83985/396) or perhaps as a [combination of colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29632352/328397) using additive, and subtractive complimentary colors.

That being said, I want to simplify a large prime number, and understand how it compares to the other primes that might exist in the space.

I recall that there was a theory exposed in the past year that said that all primes are within a range of 20,000 (or something) of the previous prime.

My question: how do I estimate the quantity of primes prior to a given number?

Comment: The [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) states that the number of primes that are at most $n$ approaches $n / \ln n$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: "I recall that there was a theory exposed in the past year that said that all primes are within a range of 20,000 (or something) of the previous prime." This is not true!  it is possible to come up with a pair of numbers, arbitrarily far apart, that have no primes between them: $n!+1$ and $n!+n+1$ have $n-1$ numbers between them (excluding the endpoints), and all are composite: $n!+k$ is divisible by $k$ for $k \le n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of Yitang Zhang (and improved by James Maynard) in 2013 was that there exist infinitely many primes which differ by some fixed number $\leq 600$. This isn't helpful in your problem.

The number of primes smaller than $n$ is given by the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), $\pi(n)$.

It is known that $\frac{\pi(n)}{n/\log n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, so one approximation would be $\frac{n}{\log n}$. You can read the Wikipedia page for further asymptotics and other things.

Comment: Does dividing the fixed number you describe approximately equal the counting prime function for n?

Comment: No. $\frac{n}{600}$ grows linearly. $\frac{n}{\log n}$ grows sub-linearly.